# Realm database file size

Tags: ios, swift, realm

My current realm file weights about 700mb. It is very many for simple iOS application. How can I get compressed copy of it? I tried to do it using `realm.writeCopyToURL(url)` from [official documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#file-size--tracking-of-intermediate-versions), but it didn't help me. What problem can be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Realm database is 700 MB and your app is very simple, then there's probably something wrong with your db.

Try using [Realm Browser](https://itunes.apple.com/app/realm-browser/id1007457278) to inspect the database and see if there's something wrong.

Also, if you added images to the database, I would suggest saving them directly to the filesystem instead and just save the path of the image in the database.